Why do plain TeX's insertion commands start a new group?
In plain.tex, insertion commands are defined as
\newinsert\topins
\newif\ifp@ge \newif\if@mid
\def\topinsert{\@midfalse\p@gefalse\@ins}
\def\midinsert{\@midtrue\@ins}
\def\pageinsert{\@midfalse\p@getrue\@ins}
\skip\topins=\z@skip % no space added when a topinsert is present
\count\topins=1000 % magnification factor (1 to 1)
\dimen\topins=\maxdimen % no limit per page
\def\@ins{\par\begingroup\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup} % start a \vbox
\def\endinsert{\egroup % finish the \vbox
  \if@mid \dimen@\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@ \advance\dimen@12\p@
    \advance\dimen@\pagetotal \advance\dimen@-\pageshrink
    \ifdim\dimen@>\pagegoal\@midfalse\p@gefalse\fi\fi
  \if@mid \bigskip\box\z@\bigbreak
  \else\insert\topins{\penalty100 % floating insertion
    \splittopskip\z@skip
    \splitmaxdepth\maxdimen \floatingpenalty\z@
    \ifp@ge \dimen@\dp\z@
    \vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\z@\kern-\dimen@}% depth is zero
    \else \box\z@\nobreak\bigskip\fi}\fi\endgroup}

Why does \@ins need to start a group with \begingroup that is ended by \endinsert with \endgroup? As far as I can tell, all of the changes that happen on the topmost level between \begingroup and \endgroup can safely leak outside:

\box0 is set to a \vbox of the material to be inserted, then emptied when it is unboxed; but this doesn't matter since \box0 is just a scratch register.
\dimen0 is set to a height to be compared against \pagegoal, but again this doesn't matter since \dimen0 is just a scratch register.
\if@mid and \ifp@ge might be set to false, but this also doesn't matter since they are always re-set before \@ins by \top/mid/pageinsert.

Am I overlooking something here?

I assume it is just to preserve the scratch registers.
You say "it doesn't matter" if the value of \dimen0 changes which is arguably true but historically many people have introduced bugs by using scratch registers and assuming their values were still valid later. Not unnecessarily changing them offers some protection for users who may not have expected using insert to reset \dimen0.

Is there any reason it has to be \begingroup instead of \bgroup (like after the \vbox)?

@rabbitgrowth probably just helps matching by eye groups just used for grouping (begingroup, which can't be used with vbox) from box groups and macro argument delimiters, but you are asking what was in D Knuth's head 50+ years ago, hard to know exactly.
